# about superposition of two sinusoidal waves

Tags: waves, interference

I am reading a material on introduction of interference and superposition. To go deeper, I want to know how the math works in superposition, from wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28wave_propagation%29

I got the general math for two waves that

$$U_1(r, t) = A_1\exp[i(\phi_1(r)-\omega t], U_2(r, t) = A_2\exp[i(\phi_2(r)-\omega t]$$

Considering $$I = \int (U_1+U_2)^2 dt$$

It gives that
$$
  I = I_1 + I_2 + 2\sqrt{I_1I_2}\cos[\phi_1(r)-\phi_2(r)]
$$

To make it simple, I want to try obtain this by considering the simple sinusoidal waves

$$U_1(x,t) = A_1\sin(kx + 2\pi f t + \phi_1), 
 U_2(x,t) = A_2\sin(kx + 2\pi f t + \phi_2)
$$
which gives

$$
  I = \int_0^T|U_1(x,t) + U_2(x,t)|^2dt = \frac{I_1}{2f} + \frac{I_2}{2f} + \frac{2\sqrt{I_1I_2}\cos(\phi_1 -\phi_2)}{f}
$$

where $T=1/f$ is the period of the sinusoidal wave. The result I obtain is pretty much the same as the one given in the wiki but I got the $f$ in the denominator, why is that? and what's that stand for physically?

Comment: intensity is proportional to $A^2$

Comment: that's my question, where it comes wrong with the math? I did the integral myself and with mathematica, I got the same answer ：（

Comment: You just made a mistake and did not define $I_1$ and $I_2$ in the same way that you defined $I$. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you integrate to $T = \frac{1}{f}$ instead of integrating over unit time. If you had integrated over unit time, the $f$ would have disappeared from the denominator. Energy per unit time makes more sense than energy per cycle of the oscillation. And obviously if energy per unit time is some value, then energy per cycle is $1/f$ of that quantity.

Note that the first integral you show didn't have limits on it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I integrate from 0 to a unit time, i.e. 0 to 1, the sin term will remain in the result !?

Comment: If you integrate over one complete cycle and then divide by $T$ (multiply by $f$) to get the average intensity per unit time, you don't run into that problem...

Comment: Oh, I see, that's how we average them in time. Thanks a lot

Comment: Misses the point that if $I_1$ had been correctly defined as the integral of $U_1$ over time instead of as $A_1^{2}$, then the correct answer would be obtained whatever the limits. It's just a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not been consistent in your definition of $I_1$, $I_2$ compared with how you have defined $I$.

I think it should be:
$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1/f} U_1^{2}\ dt$$

If I use $U_1 = A_1\sin (2\pi f t + \phi)$, then $I_1 = A_1^{2}/2f$, so the first term in your answer *is* actually $I_1$ and so on..., as you require.

i.e. Isn't the problem that you have just mistakenly used $I_1 = A_1^{2}$ ?

Alternatively if you wish $I$ to represent a time-averaged quantity, rather than its sum over a cycle then you must *consistently* define $I$ in the form of:

$$ I_1 = \frac{\int^{1/f}_0 U_1^{2} dt}{\int^{1/f}_0 dt} $$

In other words your problem is solved if $I_1$, $I_2$ are defined consistently with your definition of $I$.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I see your point now. Yes, it doesn't make sense to have different unit on both side since the intensity should be defined as the amplitude square (without time). But then how to get $I = I_1 + I_2 + 2\sqrt{I_1I_2}\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)$ in the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28wave_propagation%29 ?

Comment: That is what I get - but only if $I_1 = A_1^{2}/2f$ - as I showed above.